# when i am trying to run samples of Facebook SDK I am getting Invalid Apk file error

Tags: android, facebook

I have downloaded Facebook SDK and have installed it by console. After importing Facebook SdK samples when I am trying to run those samples I am getting error on console.

**Console Output**

```
[2014-01-16 19:20:02 - ProfilePictureSample] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2014-01-16 19:20:02 - ProfilePictureSample] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-01-16 19:20:02 - ProfilePictureSample] Launch canceled!
```

After lots of googling I have tried every given solution,I have done clean and fix project properties,I tried to run it by deleting apk file and clean and build project again but its not working,I have changed min sdk version as well as target SdK version in manifest file.but its not running on real device as well as AVd.I am getting same error in every Facebook sample.

please help me ...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution of above question is here.

1. add Facebook sdk as a library in samples by Right click on project->properties ->Android ->Add->Facebook Sdk.
   Clean the project and run it.
2. (if it not solved then) then copy the **android support v4.jar** from **FacebookSdk** and paste it in your **libs** folder(replace previous jar file to this Facebook Sdk jar file).
   clean and build the project and run it..

succesfully execute..